# How to change python script that it continue to loop and errors with openCV

Tags: python, loops, opencv, video

I am brand new to python and trying to make a replay for streaming games. Teaching my self as i go. The code is meant to to rename and play the newest video clip from a folder. It needs to continue to run and play only he newest videos once. This is what I have so far. It sets a directory. Removes file named replay.mp4( have issues if no file called replay.mp4). Than change the name of newest file to replay.mp4 and play that in a scaled window and close when done. These works but still get error after it closes (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape').

How do i fix my errors and get to run continuity but not repeat a video
?

Thanks

See code below:

```
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
import cv2



os.chdir('C:/Users/Main/Videos/PUBG')
os.remove('replay.mp4')

newest = max(glob.iglob('*.[Mm][Pp]4'), key=os.path.getctime)

replay = ('C:/Users/Main/Videos/PUBG/replay.mp4')


os.replace((newest),(replay))

cap = cv2.VideoCapture((replay))

def rescale_frame(frame, percent=25):
    width = int(frame.shape[1] * percent/ 100)
    height = int(frame.shape[0] * percent/ 100)
    dim = (width, height)
    return cv2.resize(frame, dim, interpolation =cv2.INTER_AREA)

while True:
    rect, frame = cap.read()
    frame25 = rescale_frame(frame, percent=25)
    cv2.imshow('frame25', frame25)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break



cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use try catch expression if you want to avoid this error. 
With this your code will try to execute lines in try in case of exception it will continue with the loop.

```
   while True:

        rect, frame = cap.read()
        try:
            frame25 = rescale_frame(frame, percent=25)
        except:
            continue
        cv2.imshow('frame25', frame25)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
```

Or you can just do :

```
   while True:

        rect, frame = cap.read()
        if frame== None:
               continue
        frame25 = rescale_frame(frame, percent=25)

        cv2.imshow('frame25', frame25)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
```

Comment: wrapping entire blocks of code in blind `try: catch:` statements is just asking for more bugs...

Comment: The better solution would be to just check if `frame == None` which is what is returned when [`VideoCapture::read()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read) reaches the end of a file. catching and ignoring exceptions is a bad habit to get into.

Comment: Sorry dont understand what it means to check if frame == None

Comment: `rect` is a very misleading name for that first parameter (plus you never use it, so might as well make it a `_`) -- it's not some rectangle as it would currently suggest, rather a simple Boolean flag signifying whether the `read` succeeded or not. As an alternative for testing `frame is None`, you can just test that flag. | Once you fail to read a frame, it seems unwise to just `continue`, since you're likely to end up in an infinite loop -- one case when that happens when you reach the end of the video file. Better to `break` out of the loop in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve the problem. Just need to figure out how to loop

```
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
import cv2

os.chdir('C:/Users/Main/Videos/PUBG/')

newest = max(glob.iglob('*.[Mm][Pp]4'), key=os.path.getctime)

os.replace((newest), 'replay.mp4')

if newest != max(glob.iglob('*.[Mm][Pp]4'), key=os.path.getctime):
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:/Users/Main/Videos/PUBG/replay.mp4')

def rescale_frame(frame, percent=25):
    width = int(frame.shape[1] * percent/ 100)
    height = int(frame.shape[0] * percent/ 100)
    dim = (width, height)
    return cv2.resize(frame, dim, interpolation =cv2.INTER_AREA)

while True:
    ret ,frame = cap.read()
    if type(frame) == type(None):
        break
    frame25 = rescale_frame(frame, percent=25)
    cv2.imshow('frame25',frame25)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
  cap.release()
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
os.remove('replay.mp4')
```